# how to use awk to parse test file on sun solaris

Tags: awk, solaris

I want to parse text file on sun solaris using awk and the execution is on genome terminal 2.6.1.

I have started with help of our support in the forum to start bellow code .

starting by first part and after that we will go to other parts .

bellow code print only ADD IP= A|B|C but whitout quotes ( quote at output file are mandatory).

can someone help me ?

```
 nawk -v s1="\" ' /^IPDATA/ && /IPID .*/{ if(FNR>1) print s1 "ADD IP" s1 "="s1 $NF OFS s1 }' test
```

NB: Ref is the sum of line of IPREF here in the example we have three : [2] && [2] && [1].

the sample text file in fact is huge but I have summurized it :

```
IPDATA=A                IPID A            
IPDATA=A                IPREF   [2] =     
--- IPREF = VRID=A_1                      
--- IPREF = VRID=A_2                      
                                          
IPDATA=B                IPID B            
IPDATA=B                IPREF   [2] =     
--- IPREF = VRID=B_1                      
--- IPREF = VRID=B_2                      
                                          
IPDATA=C               IPID C             
IPDATA=C               IPREF    [1] =     
--- IPREF = VRID=C_1
```

the expected output :

```
"ADD IP=A "              
show                     
(                        
set "ELEM =1"            
id "A"                   
MT POL                   
M1 no                    
M2  5                    
AD  2                    
Ref sum of IPREF 2       
"Type vlan=VRID=A_1"     
"Type vlan=VRID=A_2"     
)                        
"ADD IP=B "              
show                     
(                        
set "ELEM =1"            
id "B"                   
MT POL                   
M1 no                    
M2  5                    
AD  2                    
 Ref sum of IPREF  2     
"Type vlan=VRID=B_1"     
"Type vlan=VRID=B_2"     
)                        
"ADD IP=C "              
show                     
(                        
set "ELEM =1"            
Id "C"                   
MT POL                   
M1 no                    
M2  5                    
AD  2                    
Ref sum of IPREF  1      
"Type vlan=VRID=C_1"     
)
```

thanks

Comment: Your expected output is not clear, could you please do let us know logic of getting this output please.

Answer (score 0):

the follwing code works great only for the first part and third part :

```
  nawk -v s1="\" ' /^IPDATA/ && /IPID .*/{ if(FNR>1){  print ")"  }print "ADD IP="  $NF  ORS "show\n" "(\n" "id="  $NF  "\n" } /^--- IPREF/{ print s1 "Type vlan="$NF s1 }  ' file1
```

the output is listed bellow:

```
ADD IP=A
show
(
id=A

Type vlan=VRID=A_1
Type vlan=VRID=A_2
)
ADD IP=B
show
(
id=B

Type vlan=VRID=B_1
Type vlan=VRID=B_2
)
ADD IP=C
show
(
id=C

Type vlan=VRID=C_1
```